# How to use LoadImage and DeleteObject properly?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a windows application with C++. I load a bmp file to a DC using LoadImage, and it shows up properly. However, when I call DeleteObject, the memory doesn't seem to be freed. (I use windows task manager to track the memory usage)

In the WM_INITDIALOG part I do this:

```
static HBITMAP hBitmap = 0;
char* tempPath = "tabView.bmp";  
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,
                             tempPath,  // file containing bitmap
                             IMAGE_BITMAP,  // type = bitmap
                             0, 0,      // original size
                             LR_LOADFROMFILE);      // get image from a file
if(hBitmap)
{
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_PICTURE),
                STM_SETIMAGE,         // message to send
                (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, // bitmap type
                (LPARAM)hBitmap);     // bitmap handle
}
```

So the picture shows up in the DC, and memory increases. And in a button I do:

```
int result = DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

When I press the button, I checked the result and it's a non-zero value, which is success. But IDC_PICTURE will still show the picture, and memory stays the same. I am wondering if the SendMessage() may increase the ref count on the hBitmap...

So my question is: What is the proper way to clean up?

Comment: Task Manager is not appropriate for checking if you are leaking. Put this in a loop that runs forever and see if you run out of memory or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mentioned what version of Windows you are using. Anyway, if you read "Important" part of [STM_SETIMAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will see next:

> With Windows XP, if the bitmap passed in the STM_SETIMAGE message contains pixels with nonzero alpha, the static control takes a copy of the bitmap. This copied bitmap is returned by the next STM_SETIMAGE message. The client code may independently track the bitmaps passed to the static control, but if it does not check and release the bitmaps returned from STM_SETIMAGE messages, the bitmaps are leaked.

Maybe this applies not only for Windows XP, but for later version of Windows. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what's happening. Such a weird way to handle the resource, though... "This copied bitmap is returned by the next STM_SETIMAGE message". What if I dont want to send another STM_SETIMAGE?

Comment: You can remember the original return value and send that back when you're ready to get rid of the image.